# List Query string paramiters client side

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest, request.querystring

I would like to know if there is some way to retrieve the complete list of valid/supported parameters of a query string from client side. Here an example to clarify my goal:

The following Web page displays the list of some company's products:

http://www.companyserver.com/products.html?category=all&page=1

The available valid/supported parameters are the following:

- *category* (mandatory)
- *page* (optional, default=1)
- *itemsperpage* (optional, default=25)

In the previous link, the parameter *itemsperpage* is not specified. If there is no reference in the Web page that shows the existence of this parameter, is there a way to retrieve it?

Comment: you can only access what's in the url, someone would have to specifically provide that information, thru a web service or something, so... no

Comment: This should be part of the API Documentation